# setSelectionModel in QListWidget stops emission of itemSelectionChanged signal

Tags: c++, qt

In my QListWidget subclass, when I replace its QItemSelectionModel using setSelectionModel, the list widget stops emitting its itemSelectionChanged signal. In the real code, I'm doing this to install a subclass of QItemSelectionModel, but the problem appears even if I use just a new QItemSelectionModel.

```
MyListWidget::MyListWidget(QWidget* parent)
    : QListWidget(parent)
{
    QItemSelectionModel* oldSelectionModel = selectionModel();
    QItemSelectionModel* newSelectionModel = new QItemSelectionModel(model(), oldSelectionModel->parent());
    setSelectionModel(newSelectionModel);
    oldSelectionModel->deleteLater();
}
```

In the debugger, I can see QItemSelectionModel emit its selectionChanged signal, but QListWidget never emits its corresponding itemSelectionChanged signal.

If I comment out the body of this constructor, things work fine. As before, I can see QItemSelectionModel emit its selectionChanged signal, but now that triggers QListWidget to emit itemSelectionChanged.

It looks as if my call to setSelectionModel causes the connection between QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged and QListWidget::itemSelectionChanged to break.

By the way, I checked to see if I'm passing the wrong arguments to my new QItemSelectionModel. After I create it, model() and parent() of newSelectionModel are identical to those of oldSelectionModel. I also tried commenting out the call to deleteLater, but that didn't help.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a Qt bug. See my two posts on the Qt Forums and the bug report:

http://forum.qt.io/topic/63676/qlistwidget-how-to-prevent-unselect-all/2
http://forum.qt.io/topic/63674/qlistwidget-setselectionmodel-stops-emission-of-itemselectionchanged-signal
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50891

Answer (score 0):

As per the `Qt` documentation of `QAbstractItemView`, `setSelectionModel` replaces the current selection model and it won't work if `setModel()` is called after this.

> Note that, if you call setModel() after this function, the given
>   selectionModel will be replaced by one created by the view.

Also, from `QListWidget` documentation,

> QListWidget is a convenience class that provides a list view similar
>   to the one supplied by QListView, but with a classic item-based
>   interface for adding and removing items. QListWidget uses an internal
>   model to manage each QListWidgetItem in the list.

it looks like whenever you add items, the model gets updated / refreshed invalidating your custom selection model (just my thought).

Also, you don't need to delete the old selection model as per `Qt` docs

> **Note**: It is up to the application to delete the old selection model if
>   it is no longer needed; i.e., if it is not being used by other views.
>   This will happen automatically when its parent object is deleted.
>   However, if it does not have a parent, or if the parent is a
>   long-lived object, it may be preferable to call its deleteLater()
>   function to explicitly delete it.

if you want that level of customisation, `QListView` might be a better option.

[QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html)

[QAbstractItemView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setSelectionModel)

---

Just wondering, have you tried setting custom selection model after adding all the items to the list widget?